# Why so few full database schemas sample online?

Tags: database, database-design, schema, sample

It is a bit strange to me about database schemas sample which I think most of the projects will need to design a database for it. but when I try to find sample online, it is really rare (eg. full database schema for Inventory Management, School Management, HumanResource management). I know that each database design is depends on the project requirement, but I don't think it is much different.

I just wonder why there is so few people kick it online as other source code.

Could anyone pointing me out where to get it or any advice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't suppose you are referring to diagrams as opposed to the concept of a schema?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This must be the [ueber-list](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/) on database schemas. And here's an [interesting reading list](http://www.amazon.com/Data-Modeling-and-Warehouse/lm/38DZKQSFK9NTO/ref=cm_lmt_srch_f_2_rsrsrs0) on Amazon. I can recommend the Len Silverston books. They will get you started.

Comment: Database Answers has over 600 sample schemas/data models, great site.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of database schemas out there, I'd say.

SQL Server 7/2000 schipped with "pubs" and "Northwind" which you can still download from CodePlex.

SQL Server 2005 shipped with AdventureWorks, which is quite extensive and available in various versions (OLTP, OLAP, Light) - also available from CodePlex.

Many bloggers have sample databases they use for their blogs and their screencasts, e.g. [Rob Bagby](http://blogs.msdn.com/bags/) has one for school data and one for a winery on his blog.

There are several more (aimed at finally getting rid of using the notorious Northwind database for demos) on Codeplex.

Marc

Answer (score 1):

Why not look at open source projects for schemas along with the code that use them? For CMS schemas, there're Wordpress, Drupal and a zillion others, for CRM schemas, SugarCRM etc.